# Call service when new data is inserted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this scheduler which is used to check for new data into DB table:

```
@Service
public class ReloadCache {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void reload() {
       ...... do something 
    }
}
```

......

```
@Service
public class LogicalClient {

      final Map<String, Map<String, String>> map;


      @PostConstruct
      public void initializeBalances() {
      ............ map = new HashMap.......
      }


      @KafkaListener(......")
      public void handle(....) {
      .......read map here
      }
}
```

Note that these two services are located in separate Java classes and packages.

When schedule runs and change is detected how how I can call again Java method `initializeBalances` annotated with `@PostConstruct` in order to generate again the map structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject your `LogicalClient` in your `ReloadCache` class and call that function like this:

```java
@Service
public class ReloadCache {
    private final LogicalClient logicalClient;

    public ReloadCache(LogicalClient client) // Injection through constructor.
    {
        this.logicalClient = client;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void reload() {
        ...... do something
        client.initializeBalances()
    }
}
```

Both your classes are annotated with the `@Service`. So they are both Spring beans that can be injected wherever you find it suitable (as long as the receiving class is a bean itself).

Comment: Thank you. I forgot mention but I have a Kafka listener. I know that the service is singleton. Is this solution still valid?

Comment: It should not be a problem, but to be on the safe side you could make your `Map` thread-safe by changing its type to a `ConcurrentHashMap`